# bitbake error in building core-image-minimal

Tags: yocto

I am beginner in Yocto project. I am developing kernel image in WSL2 using Ubuntu 18.04. After following all build instruction , I am getting this error during "bitbake core-image-minimal"--
ERROR: Task (/home/supernova/PROJECTS/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_9.5.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'.

I am not sure if I am missing any package or it is just cross compilation error, because I followed all instruction as per Yocto project document. Please Do help.

Comment: Which yocto version do you use?

Comment: I tried with dunfell,langdale but getting same issue in Ubuntu 18.04, and Ubuntu 20.04. Why this is keep happening, only on error I am getting i.e. gcc-cross:do compile error.